# Testing for map membership with lenses

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

What is the idiomatic way of using lenses to check if a stateful map has a key? Here is my current attempt:

```
module Foo where

import Control.Lens
import Data.Map
import Control.Monad.State
import Data.Maybe (isJust)

check :: Int -> StateT (Map Int Int) IO ()
check k = do
  present <- use $ at k.to isJust
  unless present $ lift $ putStrLn "Not present!"
```

This works, but the `to isJust` part feels a bit clunky...

Comment: I see the `lens` combinators as a *supplement* to existing functionality, to help in writing otherwise complicated accesses. However, you can compute `present` just by saying `gets (member k)`, which doesn't use `lens`. I don't think there's any point in trying to use `lens` here.

Comment: @HTNW Point taken. But what if the map is buried deep in the state -- e.g. if it is a field of a record, which is also within a record? Sure, I can write something like `gets (member k . _field1 . _field2)`, but it would be nice to have a more uniform notation for accessing my state...

Comment: `use (field1.field.to (member k))`, or `uses (field1.field2) (member k)`, then. If you really want to write the original case with `lens`, I suppose `uses id (member k)` would work.

Comment: @HTNW Makes sense! I'll take this as an answer, if you post it as one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this particular case, keep it simple and don't use `lens`:

```
present <- gets (member k)
```

If you're going to use `lens` anyway, e.g. you need to traverse into the state through some fields to get the map, use `uses`:

```
present <- uses (field1.field2) (member k)
```

To write the first action in terms of `uses`, use the identity optic `id`:

```
present <- uses id (member k)
```

but I would not recommend doing so gratuitously.

Answer (score 1):

I'd only add that seeing if a key is in a map == checking if the traversal on that key *has* a target.

```
has (ix 5) :: (Ixed s, Num (Index s)) => s -> Bool

use (to $ has $ ix 5) :: 
  (MonadState s m, Ixed s, Num (Index s)) => m Bool

uses id (has $ ix 5) :: 
  (MonadState s m, Ixed s, Num (Index s)) => m Bool
```

But it's clear none of these are the perfectly appropriate lens. Looking at the source code,

```
use = gets . view
```

So we could instead write,

```
hasUse :: (MonadState s m) => Getting Any s a -> m Bool
hasUse = gets . has

:t hasUse $ ix 5
hasUse $ ix 5 :: 
  (MonadState s m, Ixed s, Num (Index s)) => m Bool
```

Another way that I found illustrative,

```
Any present <- uses (ix 5) (const $ Any True)
```